# Htaccess not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, tankauth

I am using tank auth in my project. In my localhost it is working fine. But when I uploaded the project to the server, I am getting the error as

> No input file specified.

I know that it is because of htaccess. My url is like http://example.org/project/test/tankauth/. When I give this url, it will redirect to http://example.org/project/test/tankauth/index.php/auth/login with the error. However, if I try with the url like http://example.org/project/test/tankauth/index.php?/auth/login, it will work fine.

My htaccess file is as shown below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /tankauth/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I am not good in htaccess.

Comment: check mod_rewrite is enable or not?

Comment: change `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your using apache on this one, I'm also assuming that you haven't made any changes in your apache config /etc/apache2/, and finally I'm assuming that you have an access to your server, then if that's the case, you might want to check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

in your /etc/apache2/sites-available/default there you'll find

```
<Directory /path/to/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None <---change None to FileInfo or All
Order allow, deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

then reset your apache -> `service apache2 restart or sudo service apache2 restart`

**heads up** using `AllowOverride All` may flag some serious vulnerability issues, if this is a production server I suggest you to not use it.

hope it helps, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try this (change last line)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

and in application/config/config.php

```
$config['uri_protocol']         ="PATH_INFO";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /tankauth/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1[L]
</IfModule>
```